# Different results when querying day partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have day partitioned table inside BigQuery. When I try to get results by executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
```

then BigQuery returns me 27 rows.  When I try to get results by executing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table]  LIMIT 1000
```

then BigQuery returns me 48 rows.

How is it working? I have no idea why limited query gives me more results.

Comment: I think that results were cached. After twenty or thirty minutes the results are comparable. Count of rows returned by this two queries are the same at this moment.

Comment: In case this happens again, try to [disable the retrieval of cached results](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#disabling_retrieval_of_cached_results).

Comment: Caching cannot cause this. Your table data probably changed between the calls. Also, prefer using standard SQL https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql

Comment: This is indeed a very strange behavior. @jcala97, were you able to reproduce this behavior again ? it is very probable the database changed between queries

Comment: I had selected checkbox to select cached results and I was querying records with query without limit before. Then I've added new records into the streaming buffer and I was querying data with queries described above. When I've switched off caching then I got normal behavior again.